# Unsightly problem with "argument of type string ist not assignable to param of custom type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

i got a working typescript code, see the snippet. Problem with TS is, that it states the code as falsy with the message:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'SetStateAction<"vertical" | "horizontal" | "vertical-reverse" |
>   "horizontal-reverse">'.

How can i write this code cleaner? I thought about using types or enums but then i get to many unecessary casts which then decrease readability and it turns into spaghetti code since i write way to much code for that.

Here the Code:

```
const directionItems = [
    { key: 0, label: "vertical" },
    { key: 1, label: "horizontal" },
    { key: 2, label: "vertical-reverse" },
    { key: 3, label: "horizontal-reverse" }
  ];

  const [curDirection, setCurDirection] = React.useState<
    "vertical" | "horizontal" | "vertical-reverse" | "horizontal-reverse"
  >("vertical");

<DropDown
   items={directionItems}
   defaultSelectedIndex={3}
   onSelectionChange={value =>
   setCurDirection(directionItems[value].label) // <-- this is where the compiler gets angry even if it just works
 }></DropDown>
```

Also here the approach using enum, but in my opinion way to much code or is this legit? (no errors from compiler with this approach):

```
enum position {
    "top",
    "bottom",
    "left",
    "right",
    "in-between"
  }

  const buttonPositionItems = [
    { key: 0, label: position[0] },
    { key: 1, label: position[1] },
    { key: 2, label: position[2] },
    { key: 3, label: position[3] },
    { key: 4, label: position[4] }
  ];

  const [curButtonPosition, setButtonPosition] = React.useState<position>(
    position.right
  );

 <DropDown
    items={buttonPositionItems}
    defaultSelectedIndex={3}
    onSelectionChange={value =>
      setButtonPosition(
      (buttonPositionItems[value].label as unknown) as position)
    }
></DropDown>
```

My Solution now (i didnt use the interface though..)

```
export type DirectionType = | "vertical" | "horizontal" | "vertical-reverse" | "horizontal-reverse";

const directionItems = [
    { key: 0, label: "vertical" },
    { key: 1, label: "horizontal" },
    { key: 2, label: "vertical-reverse" },
    { key: 3, label: "horizontal-reverse" }
  ];

  const [curDirection, setCurDirection] = React.useState<DirectionType>(
    "vertical"
  );

<DropDown
  onSelectionChange={value =>
     setCurDirection(directionItems[value].label as DirectionType )
     }>/<DropDown>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to work with interfaces to provide explicit typings, such that TypeScript will recognise that `label` is of type `"vertical" | "horizontal" | "vertical-reverse" | "horizontal-reverse"`. For instance, you could make use of [type aliases](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases).

```
export type LabelType = ("vertical" | "horizontal" | "vertical-reverse" | "horizontal-reverse");

export interface DirectionItem {
  key: number;
  label: LabelType;
}
```

Now, we can use the interfaces with your React Functional Component.

```
const directionItems: DirectionItem[] = [
    { key: 0, label: "vertical" },
    { key: 1, label: "horizontal" },
    { key: 2, label: "vertical-reverse" },
    { key: 3, label: "horizontal-reverse" }
  ];

const [curDirection, setCurDirection] = React.useState<LabelType>("vertical");
```